# Escape html anchor tags with [href]

Tags: java, html, escaping

How to escape each html dynamic anchor tag if URLs are different?

```
<a href="*_url">*_url</a>
```

I need the above code to be saved in the database as

```
&lt;a href="*_url"&gt;*_url&lt;/a&gt;
```

I've escaped other tags like `<code>`,`<html>`,`<strong>`... using

```
`StringUtils.replaceEach(post, search, replacement);`
```

Because they are static tags. But the anchor tag holds `"href"` as dynamic content.

How can I get this done by a `Java`method at once.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml()` from [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.1/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeHtml%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [java.net.URLEncoder.encode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) on conjunction with your *StringUtils.replaceEach*. You may want to parse the anchor tag and encode the same using URLEncoder .

Answer (score 0):

using an XML/HTML parser and getting the text within the two tags is easy.

i got it [here](http://www.jsoup.org/)

Answer (score 0):

David Grant's solution seems correct to me. 
In the meantime `escapeHtml` has gotten obsolete. You can choose between `escapeHtml3` and `escapeHtml4`.

1) Add to Your Gradle Dependency List:

```
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2'
```

For Maven it is:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
<version>3.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

2)

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils;
```

3) Then invoke...

```
StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4(...)
```